# Inversion of control in Nugetpacked library's - Passing in the dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I've packaged up some library's that I wish to reuse in other projects, these implement the IOC principals and I use Autofac for this.

Everything works when I created these library's in my original project - even after re-factoring into a new library my unit tests all complete successfully.

The problem comes when I add these library's to a test project to see if the Nuget package is working, I added my package and also Autofac - I wired Autofac up to inject the dependency's that my package has - same as I did in the original project where these where created.

Autofac plumbing / registering components

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                                        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                                        .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                                        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Model"));

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                                        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Model"))
                                        .AsImplementedInterfaces();


        builder.RegisterType<InquireEntities>();

        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

        var container = builder.Build();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

When I attempt to run this I get the following error.

> one of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Boxharry.Inquire.Services.DatabaseService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'Boxharry.Inquire.Models.InquireEntities entities' of constructor
>   'Void .ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Boxharry.Inquire.ViewModels.QuestionViewModel], System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Boxharry.Inquire.ViewModels.AnswerViewModel], boxharry.Inquire.Models.inquire_provided_answer,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Boxharry.Inquire.ViewModels.ActivityViewModel], boxharry.Inquire.Models.inquire_user_activity_link,   Boxharry.Inquire.Models.InquireEntities)'.

Example of library use

```
    public HomeController(IDatabaseService databaseService)
    {
        _databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var test = _activityService.GetChildActivities(290);
        //other stuff
    }
```

I'm unsure of how to proceed, I am thinking of toying with the Autofac registers components to see if the way I have done it has to be changed.

If this does not work I may have to strip IOC out of my library's and not unit test them, this does not really appeal to me.

Comment: Spelling mistake in your sample?  You appear to be registering `Model` twice, but not your `Entities`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My package was passing in a copy of the model - once I removed this from the new project the error went away.